# How do I keep Excel VBA from changing my string variable

Tags: excel, vba

I have a variable (set as string) that stores the value of a certain cell which is "1.0-123".
I then have to print a formula in a separate cell where I use this string inside of it. Something like:

```
Sub Test()
Dim n as string

n = Cells(1, 6).Value

Range("A1").Formula="=CONCATENATE(A2," & n & ",A3)"

End Sub
```

The issue here is that when my code prints this formula in excel, the value of the variable n becomes "1-123" instead of "1.0-123". Does anyone have any tips on how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Text in a formula needs to be in quotes, so:

```
Range("A1").Formula="=CONCATENATE(A2,""" & n & """,A3)"
```

Comment: It was so simple... Thanks a lot!